# Exporting Particles?

Tags: export, particles, unity

So I've taken the route of making my characters hair in blender with particles, kind of giving them their own physics and all. It works wonderfully in blender, but no matter what format I export it in, it seems I get a pearly white bald head when opening it in Unity. Is there any way to export it without having any changes to it?

Comment: I actually wouldn't use particles for hair in Unity. That could be... disastrous.

Comment: Why would that be? It wouldnt be particles if it was exported, clearly as it cannot be done in blender apparently. It would have to be converted to a mesh somehow I would assume. Then some kind of modifier/physics/animation to make it move with head motions/wind?

Comment: Are you trying for a game?

Comment: Yes. If possible I would like to make it fairly similar in the game to how it reacts in blender. Its pretty common place in games today to have more "lively" hair that move with the character instead of being stiff.

Comment: You can have it lively without using particles. Try if you want, but I don't think it'll work.